# Error in as.character(x$content) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r

I am running the following code, but I am getting:

> Error : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

```
#Load required packages
library(ggplot2)
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(syuzhet)

#get the data from whatsapp chat 
texts <- readLines("abc.txt")

#let us create the corpus
docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))

#clean our chat data
trans <- content_transformer(function (x , pattern ) gsub(pattern, " ", x))
docs <- tm_map(docs, trans, "/")
docs <- tm_map(docs, trans, "@")
docs <- tm_map(docs, trans, "\\|")
docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)
docs <- tm_map(docs, stemDocument)
```

Comment: That ususally means somethin gis not defined

Comment: should it reference "texts" in this line: docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(texts))

Comment: The use of "closure" in this reference means that something that should be a `character` is actually a `function`. For instance, often people use `data` as a variable name, storing a frame within it; but if they restart R and forget to redefine the variable, they are instead referencing the *function* named `data`, returning some error like `object of type 'closure' ...`. In *this* case, it looks like you are passing (as Khaynes suggested) the function `graphics::text` instead of the variable named `texts`.